# Controller and Views in a library project

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm writing a library to use in asp.net MVC projects. I can create Controllers and Views in the library project and use in the main project using the method `AddApplicationPart` in `Startup.cs`.

I created a `_Layout.cshtml` in library project but it doesn't work. Do I need to configure something else to use a new `_Layout.cshtml` in library project?

Comment: Could you please share your sample?

Comment: AFAIK, sharing a layout between different web projects is not possible. But sharing a view component is very easy. Hope this blog helps: https://anduin.aiursoft.com/post/2020/1/4/share-view-component-between-different-aspnet-core-web-project